# PHP y Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy haciendo una pagina en wordpress que es un formulario, cuando se apreta el boton de registrarse quiero que el formulario envie toda la info a una base de datos, pero no envia nada.

Esta es mi pagina web:

```
<form action="registro.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <input type="text" name="polygon" placeholder="Contraseña">
  <input type="submit" value="Registrarse">
</form>
```

Y este es el php:

```
function mi_registro() {
  // Conectar a la base de datos
  $conexion = new mysqli("base-de-datos-affiliate-program.mysql.database.azure.com", "user", "psswd", "base_de_datos");

  // Validar los datos
  if (empty($_POST["nombre"])) {
    die("Por favor, ingrese su nombre.");
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    die("Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico.");
  }

  if (empty($_POST["contrasena"])) {
    die("Por favor, ingrese su contraseña.");
  }

  // Encriptar la contraseña
  $contrasena_encriptada = password_hash($_POST["contrasena"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  // Insertar los datos en la base de datos
  $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, email, contrasena)
VALUES ('{$_POST["nombre"]}', '{$_POST["email"]}', '{$contrasena_encriptada}')";

  $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

  if ($resultado) {
    echo "Se ha registrado correctamente.";
  } else {
    die("No se pudo registrar.");
  }

  // Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
  $conexion->close();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_mi_registro", "mi_registro");
```

El PHP lo puse en functions.php de Wordpress así como también en Plugins y sigue sin funcionar, agradecería la ayuda, muchas gracias :)

Comment: tambien intente con el formulario: <form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('procesar_registro_nonce', 'procesar_registro_nonce'); ?>

          <input type="hidden" name="action"  value="procesar_registro_formulario">

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress tiene muchísimas formas de hacer esto, prefiero usar el standard de wordpress, crear un shortcode, luego el ajax y por ultimo el js, suele ser más limpio, por ejemplo:

Lo primero es crear el formulario en un shortcode, algo como esto:

```
/**
 * 
 * Shortcode
 * 
 * */
add_shortcode( 'registrarse', '_register_form' );
function _register_form(){

    $html = '<form action="/" method="post" id="registro">';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre">';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">';
    $html .= '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="_password" placeholder="Contraseña">';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="polygon" placeholder="Contraseña">';
    $html .= '<div id="response"></div>';
    $html .= '<button type="submit">Registrarse</button>';
    $html .= '</form>';

    return $html;
}
```

Con eso ahora podemos poner el shortcode [registrarse] en cualquier página de wordpress.

Luego creamos una función para verificar la contraseña:

```
/**
 * 
 * Validamos la contraseña
 * 
 * */
function _validate_password( $password ){
    $uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password );
    $lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password );
    $number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password );
    $specialChars = preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>¡!,|=_+¬-]/', $password );
    if ( !$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$specialChars || strlen( $password ) < 8 )  :
        return false;
    else:
        return true;
    endif;
}
```

Esta función hará un par de verificaciones para que la contraseña sea segura.

Ahora creamos una función ajax que valide esos datos por nosotros.

```
/**
 * 
 * Registro
 * 
 * */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_registrar_usuario', '_register_form_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_registrar_usuario', '_register_form_ajax' );
function _register_form_ajax(){

    /**
     * 
     * Obtenemos los datos
     * 
     * */
    $username           = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['username'] );
    $email              = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );
    $password           = $_POST['password'];

    /**
     * 
     * Verificamos que el nombre no este vacio
     * 
     * */
    if ( empty( $username ) ) :
        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'El nombre esta vacio'
        ) );
        wp_die();
    endif;

    /**
     * 
     * Verificamos que tenga un minimo de caracteres
     * 
     * */
    if ( strlen( $username ) <= 2 ) :
        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'El nombre debe contenedor al menos 3 caracteres'
        ) );
        wp_die();
    endif;

    /**
     * 
     * Verificamos que el email no este vacio
     * 
     * */
    if ( empty( $email ) ) :
        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'El email esta vacio'
        ) );
        wp_die();
    endif;

    /**
     * 
     * Verificamos que la contraseña no este vacia
     * 
     * */
    if ( empty( $password ) ) :
        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'La contraseña esta vacia'
        ) );
        wp_die();
    endif;

    /**
     * 
     * Verificamos que el email tenga el formato correcto
     * 
     * */
    if ( !is_email( $email ) ) :
        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'El email es incorrecto'
        ) );
        wp_die();
    endif;

    /**
     * 
     * Verificamos que la contraseña tenga el formato correcto
     * 
     * */
    if ( !_validate_password( $password ) ) :
        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'Su contraseña debe contener minúsculas, mayúsculas, números, un carácter especial y al menos 8 caracteres.'
        ) );
        wp_die();
    endif;

    /**
     * 
     * Si todo es correcto, creamos el objeto del usuario
     * 
     * */
    $userdata = array(
        'user_pass'             => $password,
        'user_login'            => $email,
        'user_email'            => $email,
        'display_name'          => $username,
        'nickname'              => $email,
        'first_name'            => $username,
        'first_name'            => $username,
        'show_admin_bar_front'  => false,
        'role'                  => 'subscriber'
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) :

        /**
         * 
         * Si se registra correctamente, creamos la sesion
         * 
         * */
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );

        echo json_encode( array(
            'status'    => 'success',
            'message'   => 'Cuenta creada con éxito'
        ) );
        wp_die();

    endif:

    /**
     * 
     * Si no se registra retornamos un error
     * 
     * */
    echo json_encode( array(
        'status'    => 'error',
        'message'   => $user_id->get_error_message()
    ) );
    wp_die();

}
```

Esta función verificara el usuario, la contraseña y el email, si es correcto creara el usuario y la sesión, si no lo es retornara un mensaje de error.

Ahora que ya tenemos el backend, nos falta interactuar con el, para eso creamos en nuestro tema un archivo js, yo lo nombrare `registro.js` y lo agregare en la carpeta js del tema, esto depende de ti si lo haces asi o no.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#registro button[type="submit"]', function(event){

        // Actions
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery( '#response' ).html( '' );
        jQuery(this).attr( 'disabled', true );

        // Vars
        const username          = jQuery( 'input[name="username"]' ).val();
        const password          = jQuery( 'input[name="password"]' ).val();
        const email             = jQuery( 'input[name="email"]' ).val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : 'http://dominio.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action              : 'registrar_usuario',
                username            : username,
                password            : password,
                email               : email
            },
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(result){
                
                const respond = JSON.parse( result );

                // Si es correcto reenviamos a otra pagina
                if ( respond.status == 'success' ) {

                    jQuery( '#response' ).html( respond.message );
                    window.location.href = 'http://dominio.com/cuenta';

                } else {

                    // Si no es correcto, mostramos un mensaje
                    jQuery( '#response' ).html( respond.message );

                }

                // Actions
                jQuery( '#registro button[type="submit"]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Esta función JavaScript detectara cuando se envia el form, lo interceptara, enviara al backend los datos y el backend los procesara para devolvernos una respuesta, por ultimo solo nos falta encolar nuestro registro.js en wordpress, para eso usare lo siguiente.

```
/**
 * 
 * Encolamos el js
 * 
 * */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_files' );
function _enqueue_files(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'registro', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/registro.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

}
```

Esto encolara en nuestros scripts el archivo `registro.js` en la carpeta `js` de nuestro tema.

Y ya con eso debería de funcionar, no he probado esto así que no se si es 100% correcto, deje en los comentarios cualquier tipo de retroalimentación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Como tema estoy usando Divi, sabes como puedo ingresar el js dentro? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Solo encolalo en el functions de tu tema y crea el archivo dentro del tema